# Is $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-x)^{n-1}$ differentiable when $x=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, summation

I'm asked the following question:

> Given the function $$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-x)^{n-1}$$
> what is $g^{(n)}(0)$?

It's quite easy to see that any differentiation of $n(-x)^{n-1}$ will result in an expression that is multiplied with $x$. For example $\frac{d}{dx} n(-x)^{n-1}=-n(n-1)(-x)^{n-2}$.

So my immediate thought would be that $g^{(n)}(0)=0$, since when $x=0$ the entire expression becomes zero.

But since this is so trivial, I'm wondering if $g(x)$ even is differentiabel in $x=0$, and that's what my instructor wants me to catch in this problem.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: "Uniqueness of Taylor expansion"

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? @xbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ be a series. If it converges on an open interval $(-a,a)$, then $f$ is smooth and is equal to its Taylor series
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n
\end{align}
By uniqueness of the coefficients of the Taylor series, one has
\begin{align}
\forall{n} \geqslant 0,~ n!a_n = f^{(n)}(0)
\end{align}
In your case, the series is convergent on $(-1,1)$, $a_n = (-1)^n(n+1)$. Thus it follows that the $n$th derivative at zero is equal to $(-1)^n(n+1)!$

Comment: It seems that @xbh was saying exactly that by commenting the question

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that the derivative of the series is the series of the derivatives.

Let $g_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N n(-1)^{n-1}x^{n-1},\qquad g_N'(x)=\sum_{n=2}^N n(n-1)(-1)^{n-1}x^{n-2}$.

Following the criteria in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (7.17), it suffices to show that $g_N'$ converges uniformly in some interval $[-a,a]$ and that $g_N$ converges pointwise. We will apply the [Weierstrass M test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test). The series associated with $g_N(x)$ is dominated by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a^{n-1}$, which converges for $a<1$. Hence, it converges uniformly and absolutely. A similar argument shows series associated with $g_N'(x)$ converges uniformly and absolutely.

Therefore, for all $x\in[-a,a]$, we may conclude that $g'(x)=\lim_{N\to\infty} g_N'(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)(-1)^{n-1}x^{n-2}$. Plugging in $x=0$, it is trivial to see that $g'(0)=-2.$

For the other derivatives, it's easy to argue that the derivative can keep being calculated term by term in the series.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I don't really follow why $g'(0)=-2$. When $x=0$ don't we have $g'_N(0)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)(-1)^{n-1}\cdot 0^{n-2} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty 0 = 0$ ? @zugzug

Comment: The convention is that $0^0=1$ in a series, for convenience.  This may be easier to see if instead of writing it in $\Sigma$ notation, you actually write out the terms in the series and try differentiating. You will see that one of the terms has $x$ to the first power, which differentiates to a constant.